# How to blink nodes after successfully get position of nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, d3.js

I am using ***d3js*** and set svg with `g` and `circle` all I have done successfully, getting records from json set the node position with proper line but I want to blink the nodes after set to the specified position by increase the radious and decrease the radious simultaneously till I click on any node.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have used this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795 everything running fine just want to blink these three nodes simultaneously.

Comment: you saying that they should be blinking all time unless you click on it..?

Comment: Yes they must blink all the time unless and until I click on anyone of it.

Comment: Yes exactly like http://jsfiddle.net/tq9et7bo/9/ but for all nodes.

Comment: Yes circle must blink.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tq9et7bo/12/

Comment: Amazing that's what I am looking for thank you so much

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: Is it possible to run this till the page refresh I mean always until any process done on page?

Comment: do you meam permanent blink?

Comment: Yes I want to blink it always.

Comment: I got it just need to use setInterval(function () { $('.node').fadeTo('slow', 0.4).fadeTo('slow', 5.0); }, 1500); inside blink function that's it. Thank you all for help specially MKA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely right as MKA gives you the solution just do follow steps to implement it.

Just create the css class name node and set that class in your circle

```
.node {
            fill: #000;
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
```

Now set class node in your circle as you mentioned that you are using circle

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(json.nodes)
                .enter().append("g");

node.append("circle")
             .attr('class', 'node')
             .attr("r", your value);
```

and call after create the function blink:

```
 force
            .nodes(nodes)
            .links(links)
            .alpha(0.1)
            .friction(0.3)
            .gravity(0.3)
            .theta(1)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();
            blink();  //Here it is called
```

//function for blink effect

```
 function blink() {
            for (i = 0; i != 30; i++) {
                $('.node').fadeTo('slow', 0.1).fadeTo('slow', 5.0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much 0MV1 too.

Comment: @OMV1, what if I only want some specific nodes to blink?
For eg. if (node.<someproperty> == "abc") only blink that node

Comment: @sigmabeta I don't have any idea about setting specific name but in my case, I just set one property = true in json by which I just checked that property is true and set those nodes blinkable.